# Ssis logging doesnt work in absense of folder

Tags: ssis

I have setup ssis logging to a text file. In the connection manager I have selected create file and given path as c:\logs\log.txt

Notice that log file is not generated if the log folder is absent. How to ensure that folder is created if not exists? I tried choosing create folder on connection manager but that is also not creating the log file in absence of the c:\log folder.

How to ensure folder is auto created and log is always generated?

Comment: First why wouldnt you make sure it exists before deploying your code?  If you need to you can try to have your first step in your SSIS package check for folder and create it if it does not exist.

Comment: Yes i tried that too. If 1st task is create folder and the 2nd task is made to throw an error, then, the folder is created but the log file isn't produced in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have a chicken and egg scenario here. Consider the following replication of your problem

[image]

I have the connection manager driven by a variable `LogFileName` which generates the date and time. That file lives in whatever folder is specified by `LogPath` and the first thing my package does is create the folder if it does not already exist. "This thing can run anywhere and all is good." I've said that plenty and have the scars to show for it.

The following shows the events you can choose to log (based on what is in my package).

[image]

I am only logging OnPostExecute events. So I'm good, right? Because the post execute event won't fire until after that File System Task has completed.

If that were the case, you wouldn't have posted a question.

The first event that a package generates is a PackageStart event. Look at that list of events - no ability to filter that out. It doesn't matter whether you want that event logged or not, the logging handlers hear the PackageStart event and record it. Always.

The specified Text file logger should be used to record the data and it's ready to record PackageStart to file... "oh that path doesn't exist."

It *will* exist once the very first task (File System Task, Create Folder) has completed but alas, it it too late. You either get the complete sequence of events or none.

In your Output window, you would see something like the following

> SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\PackageDeploymentModel\PackageDeploymentModel\ChickenAndEgg_Logging.dtsx" starting.

> Error: 0xC001404B at ChickenAndEgg_Logging, Log provider "SSIS log provider for Text files": The SSIS logging provider has failed to open the log. Error code: 0x80070003.

> The system cannot find the path specified.

> Error: 0xC001404B at ChickenAndEgg_Logging, Log provider "SSIS log provider for Text
> files": The SSIS logging provider has failed to open the log. Error code: 0x80070003.

> The system cannot find the path specified.

> SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\PackageDeploymentModel\PackageDeploymentModel\ChickenAndEgg_Logging.dtsx" finished: Success.

The package will show your Control Flow objects as all having gone green/OK and the status message will say it "Package execution completed with success" but on the results tab, you'll have a red X showing the log provider couldn't open the log.

### What do I do

Preconfigure your environments as part of the package deployment process. When we used the native logger as you're inquiring about, we had a document that laid out all that new developers/new servers needed to have done to ensure all of this stuff was laid out and configured as it needed to be.

Unless a client has a strong business case for using the classic logging methodology, I would encourage them to not use it and instead rely on the SSISDB's native logging. It's cleaner, easier to manage, no special setup required. To quote the fine folks in Cupertino - it just works

Comment: How to access the ssis db logs. Do these need any configuration?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15